# How to exclude nodes connected to a specific node from Neo4j Cypher search results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to perform a Neo4J Cypher query where I exclude the nodes from the result that are connected to a specific node.

I'm using that query below, but it's very slow (several seconds).

What I do below is to first get the node (of the Context type), which the other nodes should not be connected to.

Then I make the next query, finding the nodes, created by the same user but in another context "`help`" and exclude those of them that are also connected to the "`private`" context.

```
MATCH (u:User{uid:'6dbe5450-852d-11e4-9c48-b552fc8c2b90'}), 
(ctxa:Context{name:"private"}), ctxa-[:BY]->u 
WITH ctxa,u MATCH (s:Statement), (ctx:Context{name:"help"}), ctx-[:BY]->u, 
s-[:IN]->ctx, s-[:BY]->u 
WHERE NOT s-[:IN]->ctxa 
RETURN DISTINCT s.uid ORDER BY s.timestamp DESC;
```

Anyone has a better idea?

UPDATE: I also tried this:

```
MATCH (u:User{uid:'b9745f70-a13f-11e3-98c5-476729c16049'}), (s:Statement), 
(ctx:Context{name:"private"}), ctx-[:BY]->u, s-[:IN]->ctx, s-[:BY]->u 
WITH s AS sta, u MATCH (s:Statement), (ctx:Context{name:"help"}), 
ctx-[:BY]->u, s-[:IN]->ctx, s-[rel:BY]->u WHERE s <> sta RETURN DISTINCT s;
```

Comment: deemeetree, I think you could probably reduce the complexity of your queries to arrive at something a little "leaner".  Can you explain your data model a bit and the goal of the query?

Comment: @DaveBennett here is the description of the data model: http://noduslabs.com/cases/graph-database-structure-specification/ - it kind of has to be this way, because i use it for text network analysis app http://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus – if you have any ideas how to make it more simple, i would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that that using `DISTINCT` in the query really improved the speed:

```
MATCH (u:User{uid:'b9745f70-a13f-11e3-98c5-476729c16049'}), 
(ctxa:Context{name:"private"}), ctxa-[:BY]->u 
WITH DISTINCT ctxa,u 
MATCH (s:Statement), s-[rel:BY]->u, (ctx:Context{name:"bodypractices"}), 
ctx-[:BY]->u, s-[:IN]->ctx  
WHERE NOT s-[:IN]->ctxa 
RETURN DISTINCT s;
```

Basically the problem was that I was not using `DISTINCT` with the first `WITH` clause and because of the structure of my database (or maybe for another reason) I was getting a lot of rows for ctxa and then each was checked in the `WHERE` statement, slowing everything down.